How to undock the Windows 11 Touch Keyboard?
On my Galaxy Book's Windows 11 installation, if I open the Touch Keyboard (tabtip.exe) it does the following:

It docks to the bottom of the screen if I use "default" or "traditional" or any other layout besides "small".
If I click the undock button, it undocks and changes to its "small" layout on it's own.
Changing back to the "default" layout it docks it again.

However, on my desktop PC, I can dock/undock the keyboard in any layout that I want. Reading other threads it may be because I have multiple monitors connected.
Both devices have the same Version of Windows: Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2, build 22631.4169.
How do I change this on my Galaxy Book? I'm planning to use the japanese "50-on" layout, and I dont want to cover 1/3 of my screen with the Touch Keyboard.
I'm not sure if replacing the tabtip.exe with the one on my desktop installation of windows works, and I couldn't try it since windows kept restarting tabtip.exe when I kill it.
Any solutions?
